# Pronunciation of "genuine" in John Hartford - Steam Powered Aereo Plane

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, southern-white-vernacular-english

I was wondering whether there's people pronouncing "genuine" like Hartford does in [this tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AV7ZTwqC8ZI&t=60s) or if it's simply part of the freedom of artistic expression.

Comment: People often separate and stress the syllables of a word to draw attention to it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I wouldn't really say that he syllabified `genuine` in this tune. Did you give it a listen?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genuine) gives that pronunciation as "nonstandard". I would not copy it unless you are very sure of the effect it might have – it might imply mockery.

Comment: Besides the tongue-in-cheekiness of the vocalist, it could be hillbilly or Southern US pronunciation.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't trust anyone who pronounces "genuine" like that. But it's a pronunciation you'll find, certainly in popular culture.

Comment: It's a pronunciation that's commonly used when speaking in a humorous style.